# Measure of $f^{-1}(y)$ is zero

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lebesgue-measure

Let $I=[0,1]^d$ be the $d$-dimensional unit box, let $f\in C^1(I)$ a real-valued function, and let $y\in \mathbb{R}$ be in the image of $f$.

**My question:** What will be a "miniml" sufficient condition (if possible, also neccesary), so that $m(f^{-1} (y))=0$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on $I$?

Comment: If y is a regular value the preimage will be a finite number of points so the measure is zero. If the measure of the preimage of y is nonzero then the interior has to not be empty. Thus f is constant in a region of I^d and thus the gradient is zero there. I think the converse is true. That is, gradient is zero in some region implies measure of preimage is nonzero.

Comment: @NoelLundström what do you mean by regular value, in this context? Surely if $f$ is multi-linear, then its gradient is always non-zero and the preimage of $y$ is infinite

Comment: Regular value just means that it isn't a critical value.

Comment: The condition that they gave you works, only the conclusion is not correct. It is not true that the pre-image of a regular value is a finite number of points. What is true is that it will be a submanifold of dimension $d-1$, using implicit function theorem. This causes the measure to be $0$.

Comment: Yes that is correct, my bad.

Comment: @fatherBrown thanks. And this has to be a necessary condition too, right?

Comment: No, only sufficient. For example, $f(x_1,...,x_d)=x_1^2+...+x_d^2$ has $0$ as a critical value, but $f^{-1}(0)=\{(0,0,...,0)\}$ is one point.